# Count of distinct values

Tags: sql, distinct

I've read many posts here about counting distinct values, but couldn't find the right solution for me. 
At work I created a Openoffice spreadsheet connected to a database, which looks like this:

```
packID  Date    Surname  Name   Substance A   Substance B     Substance C

1     5.9.2015  Doe      John            50            50             100
2     5.9.2015  Parker   Peter           25            30             60
3     5.9.2015  Doe      John            15            80             20
4     5.9.2015  Doe      John            40            20             140
5     5.9.2015  Johnson  Jack            80            50             10
6     5.9.2015  Black    James           15            35             20
```

This is a one day example, I'd like to have an outcome looking like this:

```
Surname   Name     TotalVolume   Count

Black     James            70       1
Doe       John             200      2
Doe       John             115      1
Johnson   Jack             140      1
Parker    Peter            115      1
```

Total volume consist of three substances (A+B+C). I'd be happy for every advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain the "count" column and tag your question with the correct database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate `TotalVolume` in subquery and then just group by using Surname, Name and TotalVolume.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d514e/4)**

```
SELECT Surname, Name, TotalVolume, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (
SELECT Surname, Name, Substance_A + Substance_B + Substance_C AS TotalVolume
FROM tab) AS t
GROUP BY Surname, Name, TotalVolume
```

Or without subquery:

```
SELECT 
  Surname,
  Name,
  Substance_A + Substance_B + Substance_C AS TotalVolume,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tab
GROUP BY
  Surname,
  Name,
  Substance_A + Substance_B + Substance_C
```